# how to remove ip when container exits

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We met this kind of issue in kubernetes/docker environment:

1. when creating pod/container using kubernets/docker, ip1 was added into container
2. But when deleting pod/container successfully, pod/container are deleted
3. But seems ip1 is still in that host node because that ip is reachable by ping
4. And when recreating that pod/container using same ip1, creation fails with "address already in use"

So I think that ip1 is still in kernel but can't find it. it is appreciated if there is any suggestion on this issue how to remove that ip from that host node except reboot? and is there anyone knowing why it is fired?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this about plain Docker, or Kubernetes?  In the last step, why are you manually providing the IP address?

Comment: it is kubernetes. yes. in some case, fix ip (external ip) is needed.